# Calculate volumes based on date

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa, mariadb

I have this MariaDB table which I would like to use for bar chart:

```
CREATE TABLE `payment_transaction_daily_facts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `month` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `week` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  'created_at' date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

In my example SQL query I have single column for Date. How I can calculate the volumes per day for last 10 days when I have split date, year, month, week and day into different columns?

The final result should be for example:

```
Date       | Amount| Number of transactions per day |
11-11-2018 | 30    | 3                              |
11-12-2018 | 230   | 13                             |
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS sum_volume, COUNT(*) AS sum_Transactions
WHERE (created_at BETWEEN '2018-11-07' AND '2018-11-08')
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

I want to return the generated data using DTO:

```
public class DashboardDTO {

    private Date date;

    private int sum_volume;

    private int sum_Transactions;

    ... getters and setters
}
```

**Rest controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dashboard")
public class DashboardController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DashboardController.class);

    @Autowired
    private DashboardRepository dashboardRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PaymentTransactionsDailyFactsMapper mapper;

    @GetMapping("/volumes")
    public ResponseEntity<List<DashboardDTO>> getProcessingVolumes(@PathVariable String start_date, @PathVariable String end_date) {
        List<DashboardDTO> list = StreamSupport.stream(dashboardRepository.findPaymentTransactionsDailyFacts(start_date, end_date).spliterator(), false)
                .map(mapper::toDTO)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(list);
    }
}
```

**JPA query:**

```
public List<PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts> findPaymentTransactionsDailyFacts(LocalDateTime start_date, LocalDateTime end_date) {

        String hql = "SELECT SUM(amount) AS sum_volume, COUNT(*) AS sum_Transactions " + 
                " WHERE (created_at BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date )" + 
                " GROUP BY DATE(created_at)";

        TypedQuery<PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql,
                PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts.class).setParameter("start_date", start_date).setParameter("end_date", end_date);
        List<PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts> data = query.getResultList();
        return data;
    }
```

How should I implement the query properly?

When I receive start_date and end_date as String from Angular how should I convert it into LocaDateTime?

Comment: Thanks, I added it.

Comment: The `date` column will look like `'2018-11-07'`.  If Angular mangles it, take Angular out of the way.

Comment: What do you mean by take Angular out of the way?

Comment: You have way too much information and unnecessary code and multiple questions (how to query, how to convert dates). Please [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you paste some working example so I can rate it, please?

Comment: Time should be a dimension and if you wanted sum of transaction for the last 10 days you should have a fact for that associated with a 10 day time period. That's the whole point of data warehousing.

Comment: what is your real question here? your query is also incomplete, you don't have from and where did you get amount and transactions?

Comment: what's the rationale behind splitting the date into different parts?

Comment: I'm coping already made solution - I suppose that for different charts we need different data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I commented, time is a dimension in a data warehouse star schema, and I guess period is as well. So you should have two dimension tables, a `TimeDim` for LocalDate, and a `PeriodDim` for Period. Then you should have a `Fact` with the an embeddedId made up of the various dimensions in your schema. Then you would have facts for 1 day periods and facts for 10 day periods. If you insisted on summing facts you have the issue that JPA cannot do a `<=` or `>=` comparison against composite keys. Since you are only summing 10 days you could use a `in` clause to select 10 keys, but again, you should have facts for the periods you need.

```
@Entity
public class TimeDim {
    @Id
    private LocalDate localDate;


@Entity
public class PeriodDim {
    @Id 
    private Period period;

// need this too
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {
    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
        return (locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate));
    }
    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
        return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Embeddable
public class DimKey implements Serializable {
    private LocalDate localDate;
    private Period period;

@Entity
public class Fact {
    @EmbeddedId
    private DimKey dimKey = new DimKey();
    private long amount;
```

And for example:

```
tx.begin();

TimeDim td10 = new TimeDim();
td10.setLocalDate(LocalDate.now().minusDays(5));
em.persist(td10);
TimeDim td5 = new TimeDim();
td5.setLocalDate(LocalDate.now().minusDays(10));
em.persist(td5);

PeriodDim pd5 = new PeriodDim();
pd5.setPeriod(Period.ofDays(5));
em.persist(pd5);
PeriodDim pd10 = new PeriodDim();
pd10.setPeriod(Period.ofDays(10));
em.persist(pd10);

Fact f10 = new Fact();
f10.getDimKey().setLocalDate(td10.getLocalDate());
f10.getDimKey().setPeriod(pd10.getPeriod());
f10.setAmount(100);
em.persist(f10);

Fact f51 = new Fact();
f51.getDimKey().setLocalDate(td10.getLocalDate());
f51.getDimKey().setPeriod(pd5.getPeriod());
f51.setAmount(50);
em.persist(f51);

Fact f52 = new Fact();
f52.getDimKey().setLocalDate(td5.getLocalDate());
f52.getDimKey().setPeriod(pd5.getPeriod());
f52.setAmount(50);
em.persist(f52);

tx.commit();

em.clear();
DimKey dk = new DimKey();
dk.setLocalDate(td10.getLocalDate());
dk.setPeriod(pd10.getPeriod());
Fact f = em.createQuery("select f from Fact f where f.dimKey = :dimKey", Fact.class)
        .setParameter("dimKey", dk)
        .getSingleResult();
System.out.println("From 10 day period: " + f.getAmount());

DimKey dk1 = new DimKey();
dk1.setLocalDate(td10.getLocalDate());
dk1.setPeriod(pd5.getPeriod());
DimKey dk2 = new DimKey();
dk2.setLocalDate(td5.getLocalDate());
dk2.setPeriod(pd5.getPeriod());
Long sum = em.createQuery("select sum(f.amount) from Fact f where f.dimKey in (:dimKey1 , :dimKey2)", Long.class)
        .setParameter("dimKey1", dk1)
        .setParameter("dimKey2", dk2)
        .getSingleResult();
System.out.println("From 2*5 day period: " + sum);
```

Comment: Are you sure that we need 2 entities? Can this be archived with one JPA entity?

Comment: The answer is not what can be done, it is what should be done for the typical data warehouse situation. It you had 365 entries, 1 for every day, you would have a table with the year repeated 365 times, 12 months each repeated about 30 times, 52 weeks each repeated about 7 times, etc, etc. In real life there would be many other dimensions such as geo-location, product, customer type and others. The table would quickly become quite large. Look up "star schema" in the internet.